# Is there a method to remove the empty lines in a txt file and then opening it as a csv file in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

[Python]
I have a txt file and there are a few empty lines in it. I want to remove these lines and read file as csv

my txt file:

```
Food,Bought
Apple,Yes
Pear,Yes
Starfruit,Yes
Strawberry,No

Lemon,No
Guava,Yes
```

my code so far:

```
import csv
with open('todo.txt','r+') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    line_count = 0
    no = 1
    for row in csv_reader:
        # replacing the answers in the file
        if row[1] == 'Yes':
            row[1] = "bought"
        else:
            row[1] = "not bought"

        # printing the results
        if line_count == 0:
            line_count += 1
        else:
            print(f'{no}: {row[0]} is {row[1]}.')
            line_count += 1
            no += 1
```

what i want to see when i run:

```
1: Apple is bought
2: Pear is bought
3: Starfruit is bought
4: Strawberry is not bought
5: Lemon is not bought
6: Guava is bought
```

right now it will show an error if i run this. I tried to do strip first but it also shows any error.

Comment: `if not row: continue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please checkout this.

```
import csv
with open('test.txt','r+') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    line_count = 0
    no = 1
    for row in csv_reader:
        # replacing the answers in the file
        if row:
            if row[1] == 'Yes':
                row[1] = "bought"
            else:
                row[1] = "not bought"

            # printing the results
            if line_count == 0:
                line_count += 1
            else:
                print(f'{no}: {row[0]} is {row[1]}.')
                line_count += 1
                no += 1
```

Or improved code.

```
import csv
with open('test.txt','r+') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    line_no = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if row:
            row[1] =  "bought" if row[1] == 'Yes' else "not bought"

            if line_no>0:
                print(f'{line_no}: {row[0]} is {row[1]}.')
            line_no += 1
```